# rspec show failure even when the condition is fulfilled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using rspec to validate if a string exist in a page.  I am new to rails and following tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top
Is there anything I am missing?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

 describe "Home page" do

it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
  visit '/static_pages/home'
  page.should have_content('Sample App')
 end
 end
end
```

In my home page app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb I have following code.

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>
```

Command I am using to validate the condition.

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

Test is failing don't know why.

```
←[31mF←[0m

Failures:

1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
 ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mvisit '/static_pages/home'←[0m
 ←[31mNoMethodError←[0m:
   ←[31mundefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::
 Nested_1:0x4067a60>←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in                                                                        <top(required)>'←[0m

Finished in 0.023 seconds
←[31m1 example, 1 failure←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7←[0m ←[36m# Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'←[0m

Randomized with seed 44188
```

Comment: Looks like `visit` is undefined. Are you using Rspec AND Capybara in your gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Going by what the tutorial has you do and without your `Gemfile` to double check, I believe you are experiencing a conflict between Capybara 2.0 and RSpec on the `visit` keyword. You have two options for a solution (don't need to do both):

Option 1: Move your test from the `spec/requests` folder into the `spec/features` folder.

or

Option 2: Use the keyword `feature` instead of `describe`.

This conflict is caused by a change to Capybara noted at the top of this gist (second paragraph): https://gist.github.com/jnicklas/3980553. Quoted:

> Notably, we changed the :type that Capybara assumes your specs run under in RSpec to :feature (previously it was :request). The latest release of spec/features. Alternatively you can use the Capybara Feature DSL (feature instead of describe), which should work without any additional tweaking. If you see errors like undefined method visit, then you're probably encountering this issue. If you're including modules into :request specs, you will probably need to change that to :feature.